# Why won't Smart UV Project automatically unwrap a simple chair?

Tags: uv

I created a very simple chair mesh and I would like to unwrap it so that I can map a texture. I would like to have Smart UV Project unwrap it automatically, but whether I do it that way or try manually, I am unable to unwrap the model.

Is there something I'm missing?

[image]

I tried a few guides, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

My File: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34625

Comment: Is there a way to attach this file?

Comment: Yes, http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @GiantCowFilms http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34625

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image editor is currently showing the 'render result' as shown in the header. When the render result is set to display, the uv unwrapping will not be visible (it doesn't stop it being unwrapped, it just stops you from *seeing* it). Press the 'x' button to remove it and the uv unwrapping should appear:

[image]

Comment: @SoluableNonagon Yes, though it would be ideal if you could ask that as a separate question (so if others have the same question as you they will be able to find the answer on this site).